# How to Show Final Result in a Main Textbox Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a booking flight form. that takes the number of travellers .  I created 3 textboxes to take travellers numbers. it works good but the problem is when the user increse or decrese the number of travellers in each textbox i want to show all 3 textboxes count in a main textbox at the same time. how can i do this? here is my snippet :

```js
  $(function() {
$(".button-click a").on("click", function() {

  var $button = $(this);
  var oldValue = $button.closest("ul").prev().val();

  if ($button.text() == "+") {
      var newVal = parseInt(oldValue) +1;

    } else {
   // Don't allow decrementing below zero
    if (oldValue > 0) {
      var newVal = parseInt(oldValue - 1);
    } else {
      newVal = 0;
    }
  }
  $button.closest("ul").prev().val(newVal);

})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title>Input Number Incrementer</title>
</head>
<body>
<label>
Count all1 Traveller(s)
<input type="text" class="main" value="1" placeholder="" />
</label>
<br/><br/>
<label>
Adults
<input type="text" class="cat_textbox" id="CAT_Custom_410672" name="CAT_Custom_410672" maxlength="4000" value="0" />
 <ul class="button-group button-click">
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  </label>
  
  <label>
  Children 
  <input type="text" class="cat_textbox" id="CAT_Custom_410672" name="CAT_Custom_410672" maxlength="4000" value="0" />
   <ul class="button-group button-click">
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  </label>
  
  
    <label>
   Infants  
    <input type="text" class="cat_textbox" id="CAT_Custom_410672" name="CAT_Custom_410672" maxlength="4000" value="0" />
   <ul class="button-group button-click">
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  </label>
  
  
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In button click event iterate each loop through all traveler textboxes to take travelers numbers and make addition of passenger to count total passenger and place it in the main textbox.

```
//Place a hidden field in the form
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_travelers" id="hidden_travelers">

//place this code in button click event
var total_value = 0;
$(".cat_textbox").each(function(){
  total_value += parseInt($(this).val());
});
$(".main").val(total_value);
//Assign total travelers to the hidden field
$("#hidden_travelers").val(total_value);
```

Please check working snippet for more understanding.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".button-click a").on("click", function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.closest("ul").prev().val();

    if ($button.text() == "+") {
      var newVal = parseInt(oldValue) +1;

    } else {
      // Don't allow decrementing below zero
      if (oldValue > 0) {
        var newVal = parseInt(oldValue - 1);
      } else {
        newVal = 0;
      }
    }
    $button.closest("ul").prev().val(newVal);
    
    //Calculate total travellers from all traveller textbox.
    var total_value = 0;
    //Loop through all the traveller textboxes
    $(".cat_textbox").each(function(){
      //Make addition of travellers from all the three textboxes
      total_value += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    //Assign the total traveller number to main textbox
    $(".main").val(total_value);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title>Input Number Incrementer</title>
</head>
<body>
<label>
Count all1 Traveller(s)
<input type="text" name="no_travellers" class="main" value="0" placeholder="" />
</label>
<br/><br/>
<label>
Adults
<input type="text" class="cat_textbox" id="CAT_Custom_410672" name="CAT_Custom_410672" maxlength="4000" value="0" />
 <ul class="button-group button-click">
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  </label>
  
  <label>
  Children 
  <input type="text" class="cat_textbox" id="CAT_Custom_410672" name="CAT_Custom_410672" maxlength="4000" value="0" />
   <ul class="button-group button-click">
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  </label>
  
  
    <label>
   Infants  
    <input type="text" class="cat_textbox" id="CAT_Custom_410672" name="CAT_Custom_410672" maxlength="4000" value="0" />
   <ul class="button-group button-click">
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  </label>
  
  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: i want to send the value of final reslut to database. but the final result is still 0. how can i set the result to value?

Comment: Are you using ajax to store the value in DB? Have you tried to print the value of main textbox before inserting in DB?

Comment: And to get the value of the textbox from server side you haven't event gave name to the textbox. So please give name to the textbox like name="no_travellers" and from php you will be able to get it using $_REQUEST['no_travellers'];

Comment: yes i'm using of ajax to store my value.but i'm not using php . so is there no way to change the value of main text box?

Comment: So which server programming you are using to store value in db? And in ajax how are you sending the main text box value in the ajax file? Can you please show that code.. so may be I can help you..

Comment: i use sql to save my data. sending my form like this:  <script>
$("#form").submit(function(e) { var url = "actionform.html"
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: url, data: $("#form").serialize(),
 success: function(data) { $(".ok").html(data)
  } }); e.preventDefault();

 });  
</script>

Comment: Ok so you are posting all the form data $("#form").serialize() using ajax. But the main textbox is inside the form which you are serializing and posting data? I don't think so.. Please check it.

Comment: can i create a terxtbox with input hidden and pass the new value to it before submition and send that value?

Comment: Yes, Place a hidden field in the form and give a unique id or class to it and on every button click you can give the value to the hidden field. Please check my updated answer for it.